# Get file from AWS (S3) using Force.com toolkit

Tags: apex, aws

I'm using the toolkit to access S3, uploading documents, creating buckets etc all works fine. However, I'm struggling with accessing files in S3 so i can work with them in apex and haven't been able to find any examples to kick me off in the right direction. Any pointers would be much appreciated.